# Data fitting with curve_fit not correct

Tags: python-3.x, curve-fitting

I have some experimental data which needs to be fitted so we can elucidate x value for certain y value.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
#from xlrd import open_workbook


points = np.array([(0, -0.0142294), (20, 0.0308458785714286), (50, 
 0.1091054), (100
 ,0.2379176875), (200, 0.404354166666667)])
x = points[:,0]
y = points[:,1]
def func(x, p1,p2):
  return p1*(1-np.e**(-p2*x))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)
p1 = popt[0]
p2 = popt[1]

curvex=np.linspace(0,200,1000)
fit = func(curvex, p1, p2)
plt.plot(x, y, 'yo', label='data')

f = interp1d(fit, curvex, kind = 'nearest')
print (f(100))
plt.plot(curvex,fit,'r', linewidth=1)

plt.plot(x,y,'x',label = 'Xsaved')

plt.show()
```

Data is not fitted correctly. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your starting point is way off (it defaults to all ones, IIRC). When running `curve_fit` add keyword `p0=[1, 0.01]`

Comment: Can you elaborate how you got p0 values?

Comment: I just tried different numbers til it worked

Comment: Okay me and my friend are still a bit confused. what do these points do?

Comment: `p0` is the starting point that is updated on each iteration untill the `curve_fit` converges onto a good enough fit, basically `curve_fit` convets `p0` into `popt`. Read the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) for more info

Comment: Most non-linear solvers iteratively refine some initial estimate of the parameter values, reducing the error in each iteration. This works well if the path to lower error is smooth, but sometimes that is not true and the solver can get stuck where locally no reduction in error can be made - this is called a "local minimum". For scipy's curve_fit() routine, the default initial parameter estimates are all 1.0 which does not always give a good solution. It is a good practice to specify initial parameter estimates. If you don't have these  scipy has a genetic algoritm module to help supply them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example graphical fitter using your data and equation, with scipy's differential_evolution genetic algorithm used to supply initial parameter estimates. The scipy implementation of Differential Evolution ises the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space, and this requires bounds within which to search. In this example I have used the data maximum and minimum values as search bounds, this seems to work in this case. Note that it is much easier to find ranges within which to search than specific values.

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings


points = numpy.array([(0, -0.0142294), (20, 0.0308458785714286), (50, 0.1091054), (100 ,0.2379176875), (200, 0.404354166666667)])
x = points[:,0]
y = points[:,1]

# rename to match previous example code below
xData = x
yData = y


def func(x, p1,p2):
  return p1*(1-numpy.exp(-p2*x))


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)

    minAllData = min(minX, minY)
    maxAllData = min(maxX, maxY)

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([minAllData, maxAllData]) # search bounds for p1
    parameterBounds.append([minAllData, maxAllData]) # search bounds for p2

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# by default, differential_evolution completes by calling curve_fit() using parameter bounds
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# now call curve_fit without passing bounds from the genetic algorithm,
# just in case the best fit parameters are aoutside those bounds
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
print('Fitted parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

[image: plot]